# How to set null values while importing to phpmyadmin?

Tags: import, null, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a .csv file into phpmyadmin where several fields are purposefully left blank. I need these field to register as null values and not just left as a blank string.

I know in the field properties you can select to allow "null" vs. "not null" for each field, but it still doesn't change cell to a null value while importing. After the import I can manually go check the null box for each field on each record, but that it unrealistic considering the amount of data I'm working with.

Is there a way to get phpmyadmin to set these blank cell to null values on import?

Comment: Seems it is not clear. Having a NULL string in the csv in my case made the field "empty" but not NULL. Using \N as in the command line import gives the string "\N". I will keep exploring and hopefully came back.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282154/importing-csv-file-with-null-values-into-phpmyadmin but doesn't work OOTB for me. It might have to do with " within fields ..

Answer (score 7):

I've been experience similar issues.

If you download a PhpMyAdmin CSV file with NULL values, you'll notice that NULL doesn't get encapsulated with quotes.  So you'll have a line like this:

"1";"2";NULL;NULL

"2";"2";NULL;NULL

etc.

However, if you edit a CSV file in something like Open Office Calc, it might change this to put quotes around NULL, like so:

"1";"2";"NULL";"NULL"

"2";"2";"NULL";"NULL"

etc.

What should work is doing a search and replace for ["NULL" = NULL].

In your case, because you have empty (blank) fields, you'll be looking at doing a search and replace like this:

[,, = ,NULL,]

And probably a second pass for NULL values at the end of a line like so:

[,\n = ,NULL\n]

Answer (score 2):

Ancient question, but in case another MySQL noob like myself comes across it.

The find/replace rigamarole jmbertucci describes is avoidable if you're in charge of the *creation* of the CSV file, for example when you're backing up your own databases. In phpMyAdmin, if you select "custom" export method, you will see `replace NULL with:` and the default is `NULL`. Simply change that to `"NULL"` and you save yourself a step.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and jmbertucci's answer worked great. I did run into one additional problem. In the case with a row of data like such

`"hello","world",,,,,,`

which has multiple sets of null values in a row doing a search replace with [,, = ,NULL,] as jmbertucci suggested won't work as you intend it to on the first pass. Instead you'll end up with

`"hello","world",NULL,,NULL,,NULL`

You should continue to do the search replace to until you end up with 0 occurrences replaced