# Importing csv file with null values into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

When I import a csv file into MySQL (phpmyadmin), for all integer values that are not specified in the file but have a default of null there is an error message:  `#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1.`.  I have these questions:

a. How do I import a csv file that does not have the row-id specified if the DB table has that id defined as auto-increment?

b. What do I need in the csv file or in the table column specification in phpmyadmin for integer column that have a default of null?

Here is are sample rows from the csv file.

```
id,year,month,date,day,description,ranking
,,3,1,,,
,,3,2,,,
,,3,3,,,
,,3,4,,,
,,3,5,,,
,,3,6,,,
,,3,7,,,
,,3,7,,"Saints Perpetua and Felicity, Martyrs",
,,3,8,,,
,,3,8,,"Saint John of God, Religious",
,,3,9,,,
,,3,9,,"Saint Frances of Rome, Religious",
,,3,10,,,
```

The columns that cause the error are id, year, ranking.  They are all integer columns.  The column id is auto increment.  The other columns are INT(11) with a default of NULL.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV has no concept of "Nulls". It's impossible to differentiate between a field that is null, and a field that has a legitimately empty value (e.g. empty string). You'll have to massage the rows as you load them prior to query insertion, to replace any 'empty strings' with appropriate NULLs

e.g.

```
$row = fgetcsv(...);
$row[0] = 'NULL';
```

Comment: I added NULL for each blank field in the csv and this worked.